# Complex Capacity

Tags: capacitor, ac, capacitance

Recently we have been tasked to calculate the complex permittivity of a given capacitor. The formula suggests using the complex capacity of the capacitor. Which is what is getting me confused.

I understood complex quantities as values that can change based on the frequency that is being applied and as far as I know, the capacity of a capacitor does not change, so how is it possible for the capacity to be a complex value?

This is the formula they gave to us:
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the source for the discussion of complex permittivity and complex capacitance?

Comment: look here http://www.ece.k-state.edu//people/faculty/gjohnson/files/tcchap3.pdf

Comment: The imaginary value of permittivity give a 'real' part ...

Comment: I think the idea here is to assume the capacitance depends only on things that are constant, and the permittivity, which is complex. Then the apparent capacitance would be complex, also... meaning that there would be real parts of its impedance, (i.e. losses) for example.

Answer (score -1):

The capacitor already IS in the imaginary domain.

Z = - i/wC